# converting a string to a char *. Heap error

Tags: c++

I'm not a c++ expert so I was wondering if someone could explain to me what's going wrong with this code. When it gets to delete[] str I get a an error

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

This seems to be telling me that my buffer isn't large enough, but I can't see why.

```
char* foo() 
{
    std::string s = "01";
    char* buffer = new char[s.size()+1];
    strncpy_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), s.c_str(), s.size());
    buffer[s.size()] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    char* str = foo()
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) 
    {
        std::cout << str[i];
    }
    delete[] str;
    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this your real code?  It does not compile!

Comment: I mean you need the includes for iostream and string

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37538/1896169

Comment: Please copy and paste your real code exactly

Comment: Why would you write code like this in the first place? This is clearly C++ code, not C code, so why wouldn't you just return a `std::string` instead of a `char*`?

Comment: It's just a learning experience for me on how to relate strings and char *, not production code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(buffer)` would only return the size of the **pointer** and not of the buffer it points to. The correct size of the buffer is:

```
const auto bufSize = sizeof( *buffer ) * (s.size() + 1);
```

or, a bit simpler:

```
const auto bufSize = sizeof( char ) * (s.size() + 1);
```

With that the correct string copy looks like that:

```
strncpy_s(buffer, bufSize, s.c_str(), s.size());
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1

Comment: You are correct, `sizeof(char)==1` by definition. I was just demonstrating a general approach

Answer (score 1):

Okay I seem to have fixed it. sizeof(buffer) just returns 4 bytes (the size of a pointer I'm guessing). Changing it to the number of characters in the buffer seems to have worked.

```
strncpy_s(buffer, s.size() + 1, s.c_str(), s.size());
```

Comment: Once you try a non-ASCII string (like `wchar_t`) that code will fail once again since the elements of a wide string are not one byte each. For **portability** one should multiply the number of elements by the size of an individual element: `nElements * sizeof(element_type)`. You incurr no performance penalty as `sizeof()` is a compile-time computation

Comment: You could just write `strcpy(buffer, s.c_str());` instead of all that gunk

Comment: The use of `strncpy_s` suggests an MSVC++ environment in which "just" a `strcpy` generates a security warning. I presume the OP was trying to eliminate the warning as well

Comment: @YePhIcK disabling such warnings would be the best way to eliminate them. This example demonstrates that the warning doesn't promote security, as OP turned correct code into broken code as a result of the warning.